# Listen to an event fired in another view

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

How can I add a listener in a view where the event is fired from another view?

View:

```
fireEvent(new SelectionEvent(this, false));
```

AppLayout:

```
addListener(AnotherView.SelectionEvent.class, e -> setTabsEnabled(true));
```

View has the AppLayout as its parent component for the route target component.

The event is fired, but the listener does not receive the event to perform the expression. This pattern works fine when both are performed in the same view, but not separated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to catch the event in the *parent layout*, an AppLayout in this case.

You can use the [UI](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.9.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/UI.html) (which corresponds to the `<body>` tag) as the event bus.
For this, you can use the following code:

```java
// AnotherView
ComponentUtil.fireEvent(ui, new MyAppLayout.SelectionEvent(ui, false));
// AppLayout
ComponentUtil.addListener(ui, SelectionEvent.class, e -> setTabsEnabled(true));
```

Notice that I have moved the event from the specific view that fires the event to the common app layout class, so that MyAppLayout does **NOT** need a dependency on the child view. On the other hand, AnotherView already has a dependency on MyAppLayout defined in the `@Route` annotation.

Comment: What does ui stand for, the Vaadin UI?

Comment: @Matt the class `com.vaadin.flow.component.UI`